# How do I write tags in a p tag without actually having the program run those tags?

Tags: html

I am trying to write

```
<p>
    To separate the buttons this way, use a <div>.
</p>
```

But the problem is, it actually runs that . I have tried writing \<div\>, but that doesn't work. How do I make that tag not run?

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace `<` of the  `<div>`  with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

In html we use code tag to show html code.

Or you can use

Hopefully it will work